# Parallel Computing with Scilab or Octave

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, octave, hpc, scilab

I have a large set of data to process [40000x50] values.
I use Matlab on my laptop but it takes a very long time. 
Recently I had an access to an HPC station with theoretically I can process parallel computing. So how can I do that? I think I can't use Matlab without a proper toolbox for "Cloud computing" so I tried Scilab and octave but things were very complicated to me.
My main objectives are: 
- Processing the data and Optimizing a model.
so my questions are:
- Do I have to work on Linux to perform parallel computing? (I use windows)
- How to perform parallel computing using a free software like Scilab or Octave ( I am a little bit familiar with Scilab).
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scilab provides several ways for parallel computing. A good starting point is the [parallel computing wiki.](https://wiki.scilab.org/Documentation/ParallelComputingInScilab).

A simple example using [parallel_run](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/parallel_run.html):

```
function [r_min, r_med, r_max]=min_med_max(a, b, c)
  r_min=min(a,b,c); r_med=median([a,b,c]); r_max=max(a,b,c);
endfunction

N=10;
A=rand(1:N);B=rand(1:N);C=rand(1:N);

[Min,Med,Max]=parallel_run(A,B,C,"min_med_max");
```

Note however that this does not multi process on Windows.

Comment: Yes, a did write a code using "parallel_run" but how can I connect Scilab with the HPC station ?

Comment: You could installatie scilab on it and perform any script through cli using `scilab-adv-cli -f my_parallel_script.sci -nb`

Comment: `parallel_run` is no more available in Scilab since version 6.